# KendoGrid popup edit window, Form field set focus using jquery

Tags: kendo-grid, form-fields, kendo-window

Context: `kendoGrid` with editing set to popup. Opens a popup Window with fields in it, in this case the template for the editing window is custom with JS logic etc. The `tabindex` values have been set for all the fields in the order we want and autofocus set on the first field. I have custom JS that runs on the Edit event of the grid to position and size the window when it pops open: `function editWindowLocation(e)`

Observation: This is relatively simple with JS code if the Form and the Fields are static doing something like: `document.formName.fieldName.focus();`

Problem: After the window pops open, the new window has focus. When the tab key is pressed, it then sends focus to the buttons on the window (Update/Cancel) more tabbing later, it reaches the fields. How do I get the first field in the popup window to focus, so tabbing will set focus to the other fields in the order their index is set?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: At the end of `function editWindowLocation(e)` I added a little bit of code to find the first `tabindex` and set focus to it.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("input[tabindex=1]").focus();
}, 1000);
```

Why a timeout you say? The kendoWindow is somehow overriding the `.focus()` event and placing the focus on the `div` that makes the `kendoWindow`. But when done in a timeout, it works as expected. Not sure why this happens, but this worked for me.

Hope this helps people with similar issues.

Comment: Using setTimeout as a workaround is a terrible hack.